# Python: Difference between kwargs.pop() and kwargs.get()

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, dictionary, keyword-argument

I have seen both ways but I do not understand what the difference is and what I should use as "best practice":

```
def custom_function(**kwargs):
    foo = kwargs.pop('foo')
    bar = kwargs.pop('bar')
    ...

def custom_function2(**kwargs):
    foo = kwargs.get('foo')
    bar = kwargs.get('bar')
    ...
```

Comment: Hint: see `help(dict)`

Comment: @heemayl or more specifically: `help(dict.get)` and `help(dict.pop)`...

Comment: Best practice, generally ypu use pop when you need to call super function and dont want a specific parameter there for anything else get is your way to go or get_object_or_404 too

Comment: If you have found a best answer that answered your question, please consider accept it.

Comment: Use pop if you need to remove the key/value from the dictionary.  Use get if you only need retrieve the value.  Provide a default to avoid the exception thrown.  The answer below summarizes it all.  See @DhiaTN post https://stackoverflow.com/a/49218410/6168549.

Answer (score 60):

> [get(key[, default])](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get): return the value for key if key is in the dictionary, else default. If default is not given, it defaults to None, so that this method never raises a `KeyError`.

```
d = {'a' :1, 'c' :2}
print(d.get('b', 0)) # return 0
print(d.get('c', 0)) # return 2
```

> [pop(key[, default])](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.pop) if key is in the dictionary, remove it and return its value, else return default. If default is not given and key is not in the dictionary, a `KeyError` is raised.

```
d = {'a' :1, 'c' :2}
print(d.pop('c', 0)) # return 2
print(d) # returns {'a': 1}
print(d.get('c', 0)) # return 0
```

**NB:** Regarding best practice question, I would say it depends on your use case but I would go by default for `.get` unless I have a real need to `.pop`

Answer (score 15):

The difference is `pop` also removes the item from the dict.

There is no best practice. Use the one which is more convenient for your particular use case.

Most times, all you need is `get`ting the value.

Other times, you want to make sure no extra/unexpected kwargs are provided. In this case, it is convenient to use `pop`. E.g.:

```
a = kw.pop('a')
b = kw.pop('b')
if kw:
    raise TypeError('Unepxected kwargs provided: %s' % list(kw.keys()))
```

Answer (score 12):

Consider the next example, where the use of `get` or `pop` makes a difference:

Let's begin with `get`:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, foo_param=None):
        print("In Foo: {}".format(foo_param))

class Bar(Foo):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        bar_param = kwargs.get('bar_param')
        print("In Bar: {}".format(bar_param))
        super(Bar, self).__init__(**kwargs)

bar = Bar(foo_param='F', bar_param='B')
```

This code snippet raises `TypeError` exception:

```
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'bar_param'
```

When Bar executes `super(Bar, self).__init__(**kwargs)` it is forwarding to Foo the same dict he has recived: `{foo_param='F', bar_param='B'}`. Then Foo raises `TypeError` because input paramteres doesn't respect its interface.

If you `pop` `bar_param` before executing the call to `super`, Foo only recives its required input parameter `foo_param`, and all goes fine.

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, foo_param=None):
        print("In Foo: {}".format(foo_param))

class Bar(Foo):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        bar_param = kwargs.pop('bar_param')
        print("In Bar: {}".format(bar_param))
        super(Bar, self).__init__(**kwargs)

bar = Bar(foo_param='F', bar_param='B')
```

Output is:

```
In Bar: B
In Foo: F
```

Comment: I'd suggest that this use case is dangerous.  Build a new `kwargs` for any subsequent class intialization with the expected parameters.  You should not modify the parent `kwargs` for onward use.  That has a code smell.

Answer (score 6):

So the get and pop functions do very different things

get is used to return a value for a given key in the dictionary

pop removes the value from the dictionary and returns the removed value

All of the dictionary functions are documented here (for python3): https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict