# What's the difference between pop() versus getting key from dict?

Tags: python, python-3.x

An example project I was following uses `pop('password')` to get the `password` key from a dictionary rather than using `data['password']` or 'data.get('password')`.

Example:

```
    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        if 'password' in validated_data:
            password = validated_data.pop('password')
            instance.set_password(password)

        if 'email' in validated_data:
            instance.email = validated_data['email']
            instance.save()
```

I do understand the purpose of `pop()` when using an index, or just blatantly getting the last value from a list, but when specifying a key it doesn't seem that `pop()` is the right tool for the job.

What's the difference between these two? Seems a different means to the same end, but I'm trying to understand the developer's rationalization.

Comment: To respond to recommendation of closing due to being opinion-based, really only the selection of whether or not to use it would be opinion-based, but understanding the value in one approach over the other is what I'm asking, not what I should use.

Comment: The docs are pretty clear on what dict.pop does. What additional information do you need? How do you feel pop of an index differs from pop of a key?

Comment: Well the question was in regards to advantages/disadvantages, I know functionally what it does, it just doesn't seem like a logical choice so I was hoping to get insight into the rationale of using it in this context. I suppose the advantage is just to remove it from the data structure to prevent further use later. Someone had answered this otherwise I'd have deleted (for future readers, consider this question void).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: Difference between kwargs.pop() and kwargs.get()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49218302/python-difference-between-kwargs-pop-and-kwargs-get)

Answer (score 0):

`pop()` may return the same value as indexing into the dict or a list, but it also removes the element from the data structure which the latter do not.

Also, there is no "last value" in a dict, since it's unordered. And you can also get the last element from a list by doing a negative index or an index of `len(l) - 1`.

Comment: Right, so I suppose its a matter of preference, no underlying advantages? If you wanted `validated_data` to no longer have the `password` key then `pop()` would be the correct approach.

Comment: to get the last element of the list you don't need len at all. my_list[-1] will get the last element of the list

Comment: @CodeSpent, the two operations do fundamentally different things. Though if you're asking if theres an advantage over doing a `pop()` and then re-writing the data, vs. just overwriting the data, the latter would be better. Not only do you make your code concise, but you also mitigate the data structure from resizing itself dynamically, which can be costly

Comment: @H_DANILO i did mention that you can do a negative index